# Generate redeem code In-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In my application the user should have the ability to buy a code that he is able to redeem on another device. The problem with this is that In-app billing doesn't automatically generate a code for you. However, it does generate a purchase token. I have come up with two possible solutions, but I don't know what to do. Here are my options:

1. Use an algorithm to make the purchase token shorter and use that as the code. (Not sure if this will have security concerns as the code may be redeems from another device.)
2. Use a server and the Purchase Status to generate a code and manage the available and used codes.

Comment: But if use has same account and same application, then in-app purchase will be available on all his/her devices automatically. Why do you need a code then?

Comment: The thing is it won't be the same account. The purchaser can give this code to their friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very bold to implement something like this. If you want to give users opportunity to give codes to others as a present, then you will need to have a server and keep your codes, as well as information on who and when redeemed it on the server. And this must be very secure and very reliable. This sounds as the option two.

Comment: Sounds like the right answer. I can do that by using the Purchase API I think. Anyways as for the solution, I think reliability might be the only concern. Using the purchase token would have been good except that it wasn't designed for that and I'm probably not allowed to use that for something as that. It also wouldn't be very secure.